# Laravel datatables error on default search

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4, datatables

Have my datatables working good, however if I use the default search box, it brings up the following error. I can't see where I fix this as I assumed that this should work out the box.

I don't want to configure any custom search. Have I broken this or is this a bug?

ERROR

```
DataTables warning: table id=loadBookings - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loadBookings').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('api/bookings') }}",
        "autoWidth": false,
        "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
                { 'sWidth': '40px', "bSearchable": true},
                { "sWidth": "75px", "bSearchable": true},
                { 'sWidth': '80px', "bSearchable": true},
                { 'sWidth': '35px', "bSearchable": true},
                { 'sWidth': '35px', "bSearchable": true},
                { 'sWidth': '55px', "bSearchable": true}
            ],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });

});
```

JSON

{

```
"sEcho": 0,
"iTotalRecords": 1,
"iTotalDisplayRecords": 1,
"aaData": [
    {
        "0": "Title",
        "1": "Name",
        "2": "Joe Smith",
        "3": "Accepted",
        "4": " 07 Oct 2015",
        "5": " <a href="">Update</a>",
        "6": "Item 1",
        "7": "Accepted",
        "DT_RowClass": "accepted"
    }
],
"sColumns": [
    "bookings.id",
    "bookings.title",
    { },
    "bookings.location",
    "bookings.id",
    "bookings.time_id",
    "user.name as user_name",
    "bookings.start",
    "bookings.end",
    "bookings.user_id",
    "title",
    "actions"
]
```

}

Comment: Please post the sample return of `URL::to('api/bookings')`

Comment: Thanks, have updated with the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Check this from your JSON:

```
"5": " <a href="">Update</a>", // INVALID JSON
```

It should be `"5": " <a href=\"\">Update</a>",` or `"5": " <a href=''>Update</a>",`

Comment: For the purpose of the question, I took out some sensitive information.  I may well have added rogue characters.

Comment: just simply change the sensitive information. please post it again